# How to ignore the blank spacing in array of integers in C++ while reading a number of digits from user input

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse, getline

I want to reverse the array, The code works normally if I give it a input without any blank space but it doesn't work if there is a blank space in it.
e.g. instead of 1234, I give 1 2 3 4 and it would generate incorrect answer.
I tried using conversions from int to string to use getline() to get rid of blank space but that didn't work.
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()  
{  
string n, y;     // string var declared     
int z, rev=0, rem; // int var declared
getline(cin,n); // taken input as sting n
z = stoi(n); // converting sting n to int and storing in z
int *arr = new int(z); // setting z as dynamic array of integers
for (int x=0; x<=z; x++) { // running a loop till x <= z
    
        y = to_string(x); // converting integer x into a string y
        cin >> y;  // taking inputs as string y
        x = stoi(y); // converting string y to integer x
                // logic
        while(x!=0) { // while int x != 0 run loop
            
        rem=x%10;  // finding remainder
        rev=rev*10+rem; // adding remainder to var rev i.e reverse
        x/=10;    // rounding off to remaining numbers
        }       // closing loop of while
        cout<<rev; // printing the final reversed number
}               //closing for loop
return 0;  
}               //closing int main
```

Comment: `int *arr = new int(z);` is **not** an array. Your code has some issues, I strongly suggest you to focus on one thing. For example "How to read numbers from user input into an array?"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process only digits then get rid of everything else with this piece:

```
getline(cin,n);
std::string inp;
for(auto &s : n)
if (std::isdigit(s)) inp.push_back(s);
```

Then use `inp`, it will be free of any non digit characters.

If want to process these digits as independent numbers, you can do this:

```
std::vector<int> num_inp;
for (auto &s : n) 
if (std::isdigit(s)) 
num_inp.push_back(std::stoi(s));
```

each digit will be its own number in std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many possible answers that it is difficult to answer. Either you may use all build in C++ algorithms or, you want a handcrafted solution.

It depends also little bit, if you want to validate the input and allow only digits and spaces or, if you just want to ignore whitespace.

In any case, reading a complete line with `std::getline` and then do the validation or ignore the spaces or whatever, is the preferred solution.

If you have read the input into `str`, then you may validate it with a `std::regex_match`. Or, you can iterate over the string and can check charachter by character.

Ignoring or eliminating the space can be done with `std::regex_replace` or by putting the `std::string` into an `istringstream` and use standard io functions to extract the numbers from there. **Using formated input will skip white space**.

This is problematic while reading directly from `std::cin` because finding the and-of-line is -very astonishing- notoriously difficult.

See the following somehow clumsy example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    unsigned long numberToReverse{};
    unsigned long numberTemp{};

    // Read as many number parts as existing, even devided by space
    while (std::cin >> numberTemp) {

        // We need to shift the previous read numbers to the left
        // This we do by multiplications of 10. For as many digits as we have in the new part
        unsigned long temp{ numberTemp };
        do {
            numberToReverse *= 10;
        } while (temp /= 10);
        // Now add the new digits to the right end
        numberToReverse += numberTemp;

        // In case of '\n', so 'end of line' stop
        if (std::cin.peek() == '\n') break;
    }
    // Reverse digits
    unsigned long outputNumber{};               // For output
    while(numberToReverse) {
        outputNumber *= 10;                     // Shift digits in output 1 position left
        outputNumber += numberToReverse % 10;   // Get next digit from input
        numberToReverse /= 10;                  // Look at next digit to the left of the input
    }
    // Show result
    std::cout << outputNumber << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

OK, it does use only standard `iosstream` facilities, but it uses `peek` and will only work, if there is a number directly followed by an '\n' at the end of the input. So, not very good.

Then we may switch to the preferred solution and reada complete line as a string. Put that string into an `std::istringstream` and extract from there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    unsigned long numberToReverse{};

    // Read whateverinput to a string
    if (std::string inputAsString{}; std::getline(std::cin, inputAsString)) {

        // Put the string into a stringstream toextract the integers
        std::istringstream inputAsStringstream{ inputAsString };

        // Extract all numbers
        unsigned long numberTemp{};
        while (inputAsStringstream >> numberTemp) {

            // We need to shift the previous read numbers to the left
            // This we do by multiplications of 10. For as many digits as we have in the new part
            unsigned long temp{ numberTemp };
            do {
                numberToReverse *= 10;
            } while (temp /= 10);
            // Now add the new digits to the right end
            numberToReverse += numberTemp;
        }

    }
    // Reverse digits
    unsigned long outputNumber{};               // For output
    while (numberToReverse) {
        outputNumber *= 10;                     // Shift digits in output 1 position left
        outputNumber += numberToReverse % 10;   // Get next digit from input
        numberToReverse /= 10;                  // Look at next digit to the left of the input
    }
    // Show result
    std::cout << outputNumber << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Please note: There is no need to use an array. You can directly calculate each digit by interger and modulo division. And to determin the correct position, we can shift the digits to the left, by multiplication with 10.

These are standard methods and may be found here on SO many times.

And last but not least, the more modern C++ solution, ourely working with strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    // Read string
    if (std::string inputAsString{}; std::getline(std::cin, inputAsString))
        // Show reversed output
        std::copy(inputAsString.crbegin(), inputAsString.crend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
    return 0;
}
```

You may of course use some validation mechanism after reading the string from `std::cin`

Answer (score 0):

I Learnt about vectors to resolve this problem, hope this is helpful to someone who might have similar problem in the future.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
  
using namespace std;

void display(vector<int> &v)
{
    reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    
    for(int i=0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
    cout<<v[i]<<" ";
}
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> n;
    int size, element;
    cout<<"enter the number of elements you want reversed ";
    cin>>size;
    for(int i=1; i<=size; ++i)
    {
        //cout<<"Enter elements to be reversed ";
        cin>>element;
        n.push_back(element);
    }
 
    display(n);
    return 0;
}
``
```